# Express with i18next in Typescript

Tags: typescript, express, i18next

I added internationalization into my Express API recently. I found example https://github.com/bmanley91/express-i18n-example/blob/master/src/server.js .
I followed that example step by step with some little modifications. But the main different is that example is written in JavaScript and my project is written in Typescript.

For example purposes I minimized code.

```
// services/i18next.ts

import i18next from 'i18next'
import en_GB_translation from '../resources/locales/en_GB/translation.json'
const resources = {
    en_GB: {
        translation: en_GB_translation
    }
}
i18next
    .init(
        {
            resources,
            lng: "en_GB",
            supportedLngs: ["en_GB"],
            fallbackLng: "en_GB"
        }
    )
export default i18next
```

```
// index.ts
const i18nextMiddleware = require('i18next-express-middleware')
import import i18next from './services/i18next'
app.use(i18nextMiddleware.handle(i18next))
app.use('/users', usersRoute)
```

```
export const create = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
   const response =  req.t("successful)
   res.status(200);
   res.send(response)
}
```

But Typescript throw error

```
Property 't' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
```

Is here someone who implemented same thing and ran into the same problem ?

Comment: Having the same problem. Have you been able to solve it?

Comment: Yes try scroll down :)

Answer (score 1):

Just uninstall `i18next-express-middleware` and install `i18next-http-middleware`.

It is newest and better package for express-i18next

Then:

```
// index.ts
const i18nextMiddleware = require('i18next-http-middleware')
import i18next from './services/i18next'
app.use(i18nextMiddleware.handle(i18next))
app.use('/users', usersRoute)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to declare "t" function in .d.ts file.

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      t: (...args: any) => void
    }
  }
}

export {}
```